# GetStream - Company posts no longer showing in feed after switching to Aggregated Timeline

Tags: laravel-5.4, getstream-io

Non user posts seems to be no longer shown after I switched to using Aggregated Timeline.

Code to get aggregated timeline:

```
if (!empty($input['page'])) {
    $feed0 = FeedManager::getNewsFeeds($user->id)['timeline_aggregated'];
    $feed = $feed0->getActivities(0, 80, ["id_lt" => $page])['results'];
} else {
    $feed0 = FeedManager::getNewsFeeds($user->id)['timeline_aggregated'];
    $feed = $feed0->getActivities(0, 80)['results'];
}
```

Code below is how I follow Companies:

```
$feed = FeedManager::getClient()->feed('timeline', $user->id);
$feed->followFeed('company', $companyId);
```

Code below is how I add Company activity:

```
$a = [
    "actor"      => "App\Company:{$company->id}",
    "verb"       => "company_post",
    "object"     => "App\CompanyPost:{$post->id}",
    "time"       => $this->getTimeOfDubai(),
    "foreign_id" => "App\CompanyPost:{$post->id}"
];

if ($company->sponsor_lock == 1) {
    $companyFeed = FeedManager::getClient()->feed('sponsor', $company->id);
    $a['sponsor_lock'] =  1;
} else {
    $companyFeed = FeedManager::getClient()->feed('company', $company->id);
}

$companyFeed->addActivity($a);
```

All of these work fine if I use non aggregated timeline, but my boss likes the grouping feature found in the aggregated timeline display.  What am I missing in my code?  the verb is not even found in the var_dump for $feed variable.

Comment: Can you provide the output of your `var_dump` on `->getActivities()`? This will provide me with a better idea as to what is going on behind the scenes. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Nick, I think I have found the issue. I had my aggregated feed follow the company and I can now see the company posts.  `$feed = FeedManager::getClient()->feed('timeline_aggregated', Auth::id()); $feed->followFeed('company', 1);`.  I had the assumption that any one you "follow" on your timeline gets automatically on the aggregated feed also.  But I guess not.

Comment: No, every feed is separate, and having your aggregated feed also follow the company was all you were missing.